# Count per day per category using generate_series()

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, generate-series

I am trying to generate using `generate_series()` for each day and each category, the count, in a given date range.

Table `Posts`:

| id | date | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |

Table `Categories`:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | WEB |
| 2 | MOBILE |
| 3 | DESKTOP |

Expected `Results` :

| day | code | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | WEB | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 | MOBILE | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | DESKTOP | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | WEB | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | MOBILE | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | DESKTOP | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | WEB | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | MOBILE | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | DESKTOP | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | WEB | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | MOBILE | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | DESKTOP | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | WEB | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | MOBILE | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | DESKTOP | 0 |

So far I have :

```sql
SELECT day::date, code, count(p.id)
FROM generate_series('2022-01-01'::date, '2022-01-05'::date, '1 DAY') AS day
CROSS JOIN categories c
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.category_id = c.id
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-05'
GROUP BY (day, code)
ORDER BY day;
```

The results is not quite there, I have some intuition that I should join on a sub-query but I'm not sure.

[Link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tRIXLEga)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the counts for each category per day, and then join the results onto the series:

```
select d::date, c.code, coalesce(t.c, 0) 
from generate_series('2022-01-01'::date, '2022-01-05'::date, '1 day') d 
cross join categories c 
left join (select p.date, p.category_id, count(*) c 
   from posts p group by p.date, p.category_id) t 
on c.id = t.category_id and t.date = d::date
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/slkvfpaZ).

Comment: how would I exclude from the results the dates that don't have any count for any code @Ajax1234 ?